# Export language overrides

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, language

I need to export the language overrides which i set in the joomla 3.8 admin.
I couldn't find any option at extensions->languages->overrides and i also couldn't find the overrides inside the database.
Searching this topic wasn't helpful.
Where are the language overrides stored and how can i export them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all languages strings, overrides are stored in .ini files in language directories:

/administrator/language/overrides/

/language/overrides/

Comment: Here is the exact code (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/f79cb144734333806e01ca3329a8c9a67ecce021/administrator/components/com_languages/models/override.php#L155) that takes care about saving. They are stored in eg. `/administrator/language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini` and `/language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini` for English language. Shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: indeed, somehow i expected them to be saved in the database. But it makes sense of course to save them as file inside the language folder.